# What's wrong with my JavaScript timer?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```js
var hour = 00
var minute = 00
var second = 00
var milisecond = 00

function hour1() {
  var hour = hour + 1;
  document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour1;
}
window.setInterval(hour1, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="hour">
    <h1>00:</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="minute">
    <h1>00:</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    <h1>00</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="milisecond">
    <h3>00</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I run it, it says:

`function hour1() { var hour = hour + 1; document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour1; }`

How do I fix that?

I'm trying to make the variables go up by 1 every minute, second, etc. but it isn't working. This is my first time trying to actually make something with JavaScript, sorry if I'm missing something really simple

Comment: Typo: Change `document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour1;`
 to `document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour;` and remove the var from the second `var hour = hour + 1;` - That will however be a second :)

Comment: You have a typo, set innerHtml to hour instead of hour1

Comment: Here is a cleaner start https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/e1woypzp/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have clock you can use something like this.

```js
function setTime() {
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = time.getHours();
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }
  var minutes = time.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  var seconds = time.getSeconds();
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds;
}
timer = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Comment: This works but I wanted to learn hot to make one myself... One that starts with a button. Thanks anyways though!